# CentOS Apache: basic auth returning 403 instead of 401

Tags: centos, httpd, http-status-code-403, http-basic-authentication

I have three dirs in /var/www/html, one of them has .htacces with following:

```
Order Allow, Deny
Allow from all
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName 'lalalal'
AuthType Basic

Require user lala
```

When sending request to that dir, server returns 403 instead of 401.
When requesting other dirs, server returns 200.
What is also interesting is that when checking server-info page, there is not a single line refering to protected dir, nor its siblings.

**Edit**

Error log shows:
'Permission denied: /var/www/html/drugi/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable'
.htaccess file has 644 permissions.

Comment: Does your error log (/var/log/httpd/error_log) have any relevant messages and if so what are they?

Comment: Yes, thank you! There's 'permission denied' for the .htaccess in the dir in question, which is odd, concerning it has 644 permissions...

Comment: Show us the exact error message.

Comment: Permission denied: /var/www/html/asdf/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable

Comment: Paste what you get for `ls -alZ /var/www/html/drugi`. Or whatever the name of the directory in question is.

Comment: @MichaelHampton SELinux was the culprit, thanks for the -Z :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Order Allow, Deny
Allow from all
```

These are not required if you're using HTTP authentication and you can get rid of them. (And [Order breaks if there is whitespace after the comma](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order).)

BTW, it's a good idea to keep your htpasswd file outside the web documents directory.

Since you've updated your question with additional information, I would say that you should also check the permissions in the directory with `ls -alZ` to check both the Unix permissions and the SELinux contexts.

Comment: I've added them after first encountering the issue, thinking that there is a directive somewhere overriding this .htaccess file. My web root is actually /var/www/html and this is just testing, but thanks for the heads-up anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The 403 suggests that there is a permissions error. Check that the `apache` user has permission to read the .htaccess file and that is has traverse permission on the drugi directory tree, so that would be `r-x` for other (if it isn't owned by apache)or `r-x` for owner/group if it is owned by apache or it's group.

Comment: Both directory and containing htaccess have apache:apache as owner. And I've tried setting 755 permissions to both of them to no avail.